# Writing to Firebase using user data validation (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-security

I have the following Rule set in my Firebase Realtime DB:

```
 "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,

        "userData": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
          }
    }
}
```

I want to write to the users own array within "userData" and setting the following val's from Firebase:

```java
val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userData")
```

I am then calling the following inside a save function triggered from an onClickListener:

```java
        val userId = currentUser?.uid

        val submissionDetails = AccountDetails(firstname, lastname)

        ref.child(userId.toString()).setValue(submissionDetails).addOnCompleteListener{

        }
```

When I set the write security to `true` I see an array built, but being denied access when `$uid === auth.uid` is programmed?

Similarly, once the array is present, I can then turn on `$uid === auth.uid` and write to the array.

Comment: Is the user logged?

Comment: @cutiko isn't that done via userId?

Comment: @cutiko - ignore my last comment.  I've done some further testing and understand you better.  No, there is no array for the user to begin with.  Once I created one without the security rules, then I could update the user data with the security rules applied.

Comment: You probably don't want to call `toString()` on a nullable. I would use `val userId = currentUser?.uid ?: return` (to create a non-null userId or exit the fun).